# R Studio does not work with Chinese Characters properly

Tags: r, encoding

It seems that I have problem working with Chinese characters in my R Studio.
A simple codes like the following:

```
data <- c("物品","方案")
data
# [1] "\347\211\251\345\223\201" "\346\226\271\346\241\210"
```

It remains the same even if I run

```
Sys.setlocale(category="LC_ALL",locale="chinese")*
```

This happened to both my Windows laptop and Mac.

Can anyone tell me how to configure the R Studio in order to read the data in Chinese properly?

Comment: What is the "Default text encoding" under "Tools" > "Global options..." > "General"?

Comment: Can you show your `sessionInfo()`. Also try with `Sys.setlocale(category="LC_ALL",locale="US")` for me its works

Comment: My default text encoding is "UTF-8". I tried using the default setting and it didn't work either.

Comment: sessionInfo() result: 

R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.7.5 (Lion)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.3

I tried Sys.setlocale(category="LC_ALL",locale="US") as well but still not working.

Comment: It's ok on my macbook. > sessionInfo()  
    R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)  
    Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
    
    locale:
    [1] zh_CN.UTF-8/zh_CN.UTF-8/zh_CN.UTF-8/C/zh_CN.UTF-8/zh_CN.UTF-8
    
    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
    
    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    [1] tools_3.1.2

Answer (score 2):

Run in Shell R

```
> print("中文")
[1] "中文"
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8"
```

Run in RStudio

```
> print("中文")
[1] "\344\270\255\346\226\207"
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "C"
```

By contrast, you can find the locale environment in RStudio is not set to support UTF-8.

You should not change the locale environment while RStudio is running, you can call Sys.setlocale in .Rprofile. (OS X is ok.)

```
$ cat ~/.Rprofile
Sys.setlocale(category="LC_ALL", locale = "en_US.UTF-8")
```

You can find more information in R help `?Startup` and [RStudio Character Encoding](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532197-Character-Encoding)

Comment: R studio now works with UTF-8 coding. Just reopen the file with UTF-8 coding.