# non english characters in R

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, read.table, read.csv

I have a file which has non-english characters.

The problem is that I am using R-studio and have tried everything I know to display non-English characters, but all I see is junk.

```
> Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", locale="Chinese")

[1] "Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936"

> sessionInfo()

R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252                        LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252                       LC_NUMERIC=C                                                
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252                          

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.0



a<-'黑龙江省'
> a
[1] "ºÚÁú½­Ê¡"


> x=c('中華民族');x; y <- data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
[1] "ÖÐÈAÃñ×å"
> y
         x
1 ÖÐÈAÃñ×å
> q<-'天'
```

I have also tried using

```
> temp1<-read.table(file.choose(),header=FALSE,fill=TRUE,encoding="UTF-8",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

and other read.csv and read.table options but to no avail. I am using R-studio if that helps.

Comment: What does `Encoding(a)` return for you? At least in this post it appears to be encoded as UTF-8. You should know how the file is encoded as there is no definitive way to determine that from the file itself.

Comment: Dimitri commented on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467606/r-studio-does-not-work-with-chinese-characters-properly) topic what worked for him. Might give it a shot

Comment: @MrFlick Endoing is UTF-8.

Comment: @Heuer Thanks, I tried that method as well, but it is still not working.