# How can I output Chinese characters (hanzi/kanji/hanja) in R?

Tags: r, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, cjk

How can I output Chinese characters (hanzi/kanji/hanja) in R? Unexpectedly, they are being escaped into their Unicode codepoint:

```r
> "中文"
[1] "\u4e2d\u6587"
```

```r
> print("中文")
[1] "\u4e2d\u6587"
```

This is the case both in a Terminal R session as well as in RStudio.

Desired output would be:

```r
> "中文"
[1] "中文"
```

What settings do I need to change to get this output?

[Most other posts with similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467606/r-studio-does-not-work-with-chinese-characters-properly) seem to resolve this by changing the locale to a UTF-8 one, but I am already using one:

```r
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/C/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8"
```

[This example](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/utf8/vignettes/utf8.html) with other Unicode examples works as expected:

```r
> "\U0001f600\U0001f601\U0001f602\U0001f603\U0001f604\U0001f605\U0001f606\U0001f607\U0001f608\U0001f609\U0001f60a\U0001f60b\U0001f60c\U0001f60d\U0001f60e\U0001f60f\U0001f610\U0001f611\U0001f612\U0001f613\U0001f614\U0001f615\U0001f616\U0001f617\U0001f618\U0001f619\U0001f61a\U0001f61b\U0001f61c\U0001f61d\U0001f61e\U0001f61f\U0001f620\U0001f621\U0001f622\U0001f623\U0001f624\U0001f625\U0001f626\U0001f627\U0001f628\U0001f629\U0001f62a\U0001f62b\U0001f62c\U0001f62d\U0001f62e\U0001f62f\U0001f630\U0001f631\U0001f632\U0001f633\U0001f634\U0001f635\U0001f636\U0001f637\U0001f638\U0001f639\U0001f63a\U0001f63b\U0001f63c\U0001f63d\U0001f63e\U0001f63f\U0001f640\U0001f641\U0001f642\U0001f643\U0001f644\U0001f645\U0001f646\U0001f647\U0001f648\U0001f649\U0001f64a\U0001f64b\U0001f64c\U0001f64d\U0001f64e\U0001f64f"
[1] ""
> ""
[1] ""
> print("ひらがな") # Japanese hiragana
[1] "ひらがな"
> print("한글") # Korean
[1] "한글"
```

The problem strangely enough seems to only apply to Chinese characters (of course also in Japanese, `print("源氏物語")` naturally does not work).
Other packages are apparently capable of outputting the correct characters:

```r
> string_zh <- c("中", "文")
> string_zh
[1] "\u4e2d" "\u6587"
> tibble::tibble(string_zh)
# A tibble: 2 x 1
  string_zh
  <chr>
1 中
2 文
```

The following also works:

```r
> utf8::utf8_print("中文")
[1] "中文"
```

```r
> cat("中文")
中文
```

Here is what I am running:

```r
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRblas.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/C/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.4 utf8_1.2.1
```

Comment: as a work-around,  try   `Chinese = "中文";   Encoding(Chinese) = 'UTF-8' ;  cat(Chinese, "\n")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is a bug in `R 4.0.4` (see [bug report](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18059)) that should be fixed in the next release.